# Highcharts: First X Point over the YAxis

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am doing a chart with some **stats across the years**. The problem is that the first point (year 2011) is not over the YAxis. Insted, there is some space between the YAxis and the first point. I've marked it on the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1rcb.jpg

So, which is the property to avoid that? I need 2011 to be the first element and the graph fills the whole space.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Please show your code (or better yet create a jsFiddle), if you don't we are just guessing...

Comment: The problem is that you are using categories, don't use them. Instead use dateTime axis, or use label formatter for linear axis.

Comment: Yes, i am using categories, but this is because i am developing a generic control, and it's more complicated to make it for dateTime to.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible solutions:

1.Set the minimum value for the [`xAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min):

```
//...
xAxis: {
   min: 2011
}
//...
```

2.Set the starting point for [`plotOptions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.pointStart):

```
//...    
plotOptions: {
    area: {
       pointStart: 2011
    }
}    
//...
```

Comment: How come the second options doesn't work? It's [the official way to do it](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.areaspline.pointStart)...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting midPadding to zero on the xAxis?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change this in categories. 
Use for example linear axis with proper label formatter, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/63/ - you can also add `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to remove this extra space on left/right sides.